# Dynamic Dispatch replacement for Generic methods

Tags: java, object-oriented, design-patterns

Type erasure is giving me nuts recently. I'm designing a class that performs symbolic differentiation on a math expression represented as a binary expression tree. The question is more on the design part than on the actual code part so I'm only giving out the method that looks awful to me.

```
public Node derive(final Node currentNode, Node parentNode) {
    Node dxNode = null;

    final Object cDataContext = currentNode.getData();
    if (Number.class.isAssignableFrom(cDataContext.getClass()))
        dxNode = new TreeNode<Double>(0.0);
    else if (AddOperator.class.isAssignableFrom(cDataContext.getClass()))
        dxNode = deriveAddContext((Node<AddOperator>) currentNode);
    else if (MulOperator.class.isAssignableFrom(cDataContext.getClass()))
        dxNode = deriveMulContext((Node<MulOperator>) currentNode);
    else if (SineFunction.class.isAssignableFrom(cDataContext.getClass()))
        dxNode = deriveSineContext((Node<SineFunction>) currentNode);

    if (dxNode != null && parentNode != null)
        dxNode.setParent(parentNode);

    return dxNode;
}
```

I think it already speaks for itself. I'm having methods with different names which is fine. The awful part at least for me is this huge if statement that I truncated for simplicity. Is there a better way of doing this? I mean I would love to live with dynamic dispatch having the whole derive method consisting of a simple:

```
Node dxNode = deriveNode(currentNode);
dxNode.setParent(parentNode);
return dxNode;
```

I guess Java won't give me this luxury so perhaps there is some design pattern that I can utilize here? Just to give you a better understanding of the algorithm I'll show a sample method:

```
private Node<AddOperator> deriveAddContext(final Node<AddOperator> additionContext) {
    // d/dx [f(x) + g(x)] = d/dx [f(x)] + d/dx [g(x)] => d/dx [f(x)] d/dx [g(x)] +

    // ROOT: ADD
    Node<AddOperator> dRoot = new TreeNode<AddOperator>(new AddOperator());
    // ROOT.LEFT: d/dx [f(x)]
    dRoot.setLeft(derive(additionContext.getLeft(), dRoot));
    // ROOT.RIGHT: d/dx [g(x)]
    dRoot.setRight(derive(additionContext.getRight(), dRoot));
    // RET: d/dx
    return dRoot;
}
```

So the whole algorithm is recursive on the expression traversing the original expr in an inorder fashion.

A Node has the following structure:

```
 dataField: <DataType>
 leftChild: Node
 rightChild: Node
 parent: Node
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, I would be able to live with your huge if statement if it remains straightforward, is well tested, and hidden in a nice class. I think a parser will often have these types of structures, especially if you are generating it from a grammar using a tool (like [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/) for example) instead of coding it by hand.

You could slightly improve the huge if statement by factoring out `currentNode.getData().getClass()` (instead of `currentNode.getData()`):

```
final Class<?> dataClass = currentNode.getData().getClass();
if (Number.class.isAssignableFrom(dataClass))
    dxNode = new TreeNode<Double>(0.0);
else if (AddOperator.class.isAssignableFrom(dataClass))
    dxNode = deriveAddContext((Node<AddOperator>) currentNode);
else if (MulOperator.class.isAssignableFrom(dataClass))
    dxNode = deriveMulContext((Node<MulOperator>) currentNode);
else if (SineFunction.class.isAssignableFrom(dataClass))
    dxNode = deriveSineContext((Node<SineFunction>) currentNode);
```

You could also consider using Java 8 to create an explicit mapping between the class the current node (data) is assignable from and the initialization code for `dxNode` using lambda expressions. This has the advantage that you should be able to extend the expression types by adding a single line to the map:

```
public Node deriveAlternative(final Node currentNode, final Node parentNode) {
    Node dxNode = null;

    final Map<Class<?>, Function<Node, Node>> deriveMap = new HashMap<>();
    deriveMap.put(Number.class, n -> new TreeNode<Double>(0.0));
    deriveMap.put(AddOperator.class, n -> deriveAddContext((Node<AddOperator>) n));
    deriveMap.put(MulOperator.class, n -> deriveMulContext((Node<MulOperator>) n));
    deriveMap.put(SineFunction.class, n -> deriveSineContext((Node<SineFunction>) n));

    final Optional<Class<?>> optionalKey = deriveMap.keySet().stream()
            .filter(key -> key.isAssignableFrom(currentNode.getData().getClass()))
            .findFirst();

    if (optionalKey.isPresent()) {
        final Class<?> key = optionalKey.get();
        dxNode = deriveMap.get(key).apply(currentNode);
    }

    if (dxNode != null && parentNode != null)
        dxNode.setParent(parentNode);

    return dxNode;
}
```